# Load page error when I use ScriptLink in the page head

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, scriptlink

Here is the beginning of my custom SharePoint Application Page:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TrainingAssignmentForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.TrainingAssignmentPage" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" Language="javascript" Defer="true" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
...
```

When I try to debug the page it cannot be loaded. Removing the `<SharePoint:ScriptLink>` tag clears the error. I need `<SharePoint:ScriptLink>` because I want to use `SP.js` in my code. Am I missing an assembly reference or something?

Here is the beginning of the code-behind page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class TrainingAssignmentPage : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        ....
```

I am using SharePoint 2010 and it is not a sandbox solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="SP.js" defer="true" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>
```

Comment: Did this  solution help?